# Tomcat не запускает страницу: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven, tomcat, сборка

Помогите ничего не получается .
Все перепробовал, не пойму где ошибка .
создаю проэкт вот так:

[image: создание проэтка]

**Структура проекта:**

[image: структура]

далее настраиваю Tomcat и выбираю artifact:

[image: artifact]

Tomcat работает и страница Hello World открывается.
Далее добавляю в проект Spring MVC:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее запускаю сервер и ошибка:

> Artifact testrusxom:war: Error during artifact deployment.

Далее собираю проект мавеном install и
выбираю в месте artifact для tomcat папку с war файлом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю Tomcat та же ошибка:

> Artifact `testrusxom.war`: Error during artifact deployment. See
> server log for details.

При заходе  на `http://localhost:8080` (отдельно , так как из идеи не запускается автоматом) ошибка 404:

> Exception: The origin server did not find a current representation for
> the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

**Структура war:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В логах ошибка:**

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error
> configuring application listener of class
> [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

помогите разобраться ни чего уже не понимаю.

Comment: так где сервер лог?

Comment: Лог по ссылке https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IlZ17V9VstnEsokgAzjunTCINNQVP7AMc749IJAhoXY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> Error configuring application listener of class
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Ошибка в том, что класс `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` не найден при попытке загрузить класс.

Добавьте следующую библиотеку в зависимости проекта:

```
spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar
```

Видно что скачивали библиотеку проекта Spring MVC 4.3.18.RELEASE, но она видимо не подключена в зависимости и/или не добавлена в артефакт.

Comment: Спасибо скачал! теперь  запускается.

Comment: Все работало!  Потом на каком  то этапе опять перестало открывать страницу. Сейчас делаю заново, создаю проект и подключаю  вот эти зависимости                       
              [Зависимости смотреть](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Basicprof/WIEVS/master/pom.xml) и томкаn дает такую ошибку.          [Ошибки Смотреть..](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Basicprof/WIEVS/master/text.txt)

Comment: версия поменялась, создавайте проект из pom.